# Mass Copy Files On Amazon AWE with CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

This is probably easy but it's really stumping me. I literally have about 9 hours experience with Amazon AWS and CLI.

I have a directory

```
    BDp-Archive/item/
```

on my S3 and I want to copy the text files in that directory into its sub directory called

```
    BDp-Archive/item/txt/
```

My attempted command was:

```
    aws s3 mv s3://Bdp-Archive/00009e98-3e0f-402e-9d12-7aec8e32b783/ s3://BDp-Archive/00009e98-3e0f-402e-9d12-7aec8e32b783/txt/ --include "*.txt"
```

This is throwing the error: 
A client error (NoSuchKey) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "
00009e98-3e0f-402e-9d12-7aec8e32b783" does not exist
Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining

Answer (score 10):

I think the problem is that you need to use the `--recursive` switch, since by default, the `mv` command only applies to a single object (much like the other commands - `rm`, `sync`, etc...).  try:

```
aws s3 mv s3://Bdp-Archive/00009e98-3e0f-402e-9d12-7aec8e32b783/ s3://BDp-Archive/00009e98-3e0f-402e-9d12-7aec8e32b783/txt/ --include "*.txt" --recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to configure the region of my bucket (or specify it as part of the cli command

`aws s3 cp --region <region> <from> <to>`

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure your access keys and secret key, try:

```
aws configure
```

For more options, see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-installing-credentials